# How to display the last user

Tags: powershell

I have got this list, I want to filter only the last (the more recent) line for a user.
Trying with "Sort Username -Unique" doesn't filter good, neither Get-Unique.

```
UserName              TimeGenerated      
--------              -------------      
EP\user1              16/09/2014 11:08:04
EP\user2              16/09/2014 11:00:45
EP\user2              16/09/2014 11:00:24
EP\user4              16/09/2014 10:42:51
EP\user4              16/09/2014 10:40:53
EP\user5              16/09/2014 09:51:44
EP\user5              16/09/2014 09:40:53
EP\user3              16/09/2014 08:59:03
EP\user3              15/09/2014 08:58:45
EP\user3              15/09/2014 08:57:58
```

I would expect something like that :

```
UserName              TimeGenerated      
--------              -------------      
EP\user1              16/09/2014 11:08:04
EP\user2              16/09/2014 11:00:45
EP\user4              16/09/2014 10:42:51
EP\user5              16/09/2014 09:51:44
EP\user3              16/09/2014 08:59:03
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Group` cmdlet, pipe your list to:

```powershell
| Group username | % { $_.Group | Sort TimeGenerated | Select-Object -First 1}
```

Comment: By using your command, I only get 1 result, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @expirat001, amended the answer.

Comment: Thanks ... but ... Still not working. Moreover, the column TimeGenerated is not sorted. By using your command with Group cmdlet, it doesn't return me all the results.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? What's the output?